# iPhone adding to NSMutableArray from another location but not retaining the data

Tags: iphone, arrays, nsmutablearray

I've received help from here before and I because of that help i got it working, partially.

What I have done is created an NSMutableArray in a view controller implementation file called BookmarksViewController.m. The array is properly set up and populates a UITableView also contained in the same implementation file.

My original problem was passing objects into that array from a separate view controller by performing an IBAction on a command button. When I pass the string (addObject) to the array I also push the BookmarksViewController onto the navigation stack. When the View Controller loads onto the navigation stack the string that was passed can clearly be seen. However, whenever I move too far back through the navigation stack by pressing the back button I return to where I just added the object and it is completely gone.

Im also using a Tab Bar which has a button to the BookmarksViewController.m and if you press that the new string is nowhere to be seen. What I'm thinking is that for some reason the new string isn't being retained once its off the navigation pile, but I cant understand how it can seemingly add to the array from one perspective and not the other.

Here is the concerning code:

**BookmarksViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DissertationAppDelegate.h"

@interface BookmarksViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *bookmarksArray;
    DissertationAppDelegate *dissertationAppDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *bookmarksArray;

@property (nonatomic, retain) DissertationAppDelegate *dissertationAppDelegate;

@end
```

**BookmarksViewController.m**

```
#import "BookmarksViewController.h"


@implementation BookmarksViewController
@synthesize bookmarksArray;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle



- (void)viewDidLoad {

bookmarksArray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [bookmarksArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = [bookmarksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
- (void)dealloc {
[bookmarksArray release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

Ch01GettingStarted.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BookmarksViewController.h"



@interface Ch01GettingStarted : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *ScrollView;
    IBOutlet BookmarksViewController *bookmarksViewController;
}
-(IBAction) pushChap01Bookmark:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain) BookmarksViewController *bookmarksViewController;


@end
```

Ch01GettingStarted.m

```
#import "Ch01GettingStarted.h"
#import "BookmarksViewController.h"
#import "DissertationAppDelegate.h"

@implementation Ch01GettingStarted
@synthesize bookmarksViewController;

-(IBAction) pushChap01Bookmark:(id)sender{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:bookmarksViewController animated:YES];
    bookmarksViewController.title = @"Bookmarks";
    [bookmarksViewController.bookmarksArray addObject:@"NewString"];
    NSLog(@"ADD ENTRY");
    [bookmarksViewController.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"RELOAD TABLE");
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [bookmarksViewController release];
    [ScrollView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

So what it seems to be doing is adding an object "NewString" to bookmarksArray in the BookmarksViewController. But if possible I want it to stay there all the time.

Thank You.
Carl

Answer (score 0):

-loadView may be called many times during a single UIViewController's life. Since you any existing bookmarksArray with a new array every time -loadView is called you're going to lose data eventually.

UIViewControllers will unload their views if their view is not visible when the controller receives a memory warning. See the UIViewController docs for details.

In addition you may create and work with a BookmarksViewController without its -loadView method being called so with the current implementation bookmarksArray might be nil when you try to add a value to it.

Comment: Hi Jonah, thank you for your reply. So this is what's happening, every time I come back to BookmarksViewController the array is being set back to its original configuration in the view did load. Ok, this makes sense. So if I don't need a viewDidLoad in that implementation file, what can i contain my array in? Can I create my own -(void)array  or something, sorry im new to this. Thank You.

Comment: When i moved it out of the viewDidLoad it doesn't even add the string to the array anymore.

Comment: Im going to read through UIViewController docs now, thank you.

Comment: Im reading an article in a book about persistent data. Hopefully ill be able to write to a property list and store the data that way.

Comment: You would still need to create your bookmarksArray but you should do so in an init method rather than in viewDidLoad. That way it would be created when your controller is initialized and not only when the view is loaded.
If you know the view will be loaded before you try to access that array you could continue to create it in -viewDidLoad, just at least check if the array already exists and discarding it in favor of a new empty array.